# Postgres synchronous_standby_names var not accepting '-' in the hostname

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-10

I am trying to setup Postgres cluster with 3 machines to get high availability with automatic failover.

```
postgres-01 --> master
postgres-02 --> sync replica
postgres-03 --> async replica
```

When I tried to use `synchronous_standby_names='postgres-02'` in the `postgresql.conf` it fails to restart the postgres with the following error

```
LOG:  invalid value for parameter "synchronous_standby_names": "postgres-02"
DETAIL:  syntax error at or near "-"
FATAL:  configuration file "/pgsql/postgresql.conf" contains errors
postgresql-10.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Failed to start PostgreSQL 10 database server.
    -- Subject: Unit postgresql-10.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
```

Removing the '-' from the hostname fixes the problem, But is this really required.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to quote the name:

```
synchronous_standby_names = '"postgres-02"'
```

You should have at least two synchronous standby servers, else your system will stop functioning if the single synchronous standby server goes down.